# Passing a querystring value through a javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass the pass value stored in a asp hiddenfield to a querystring using the window.open.

```
onclick="window.open('../New/FeedbackV4.aspx','FeedbackWindow','width=960,height=640,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes')"
```

I need to get the value of the hidden field and pass it as a querystring

Comment: oops... I need to get the value of the hidden field and pass it as a querystring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand the context, but given a `HiddenField`:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_myhiddenfield" runat="server" Value="hidden value"/>
```

You can use a Javascript function to insert the value into your `onclick` attribute

**onclick**

```
onclick="window.open('../New/FeedbackV4.aspx'+GetHFValue(),'FeedbackWindow','width=960,height=640,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes')"
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetHFValue() {
        var hf_value = '?' + document.getElementById("<%= hf_myhiddenfield.ClientID %>").value;
        return hf_value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for simplicity that the hidden field has an `id` attribute, say `id='foo'` (if not, you will need to find another way of picking up that element), use

```
onclick="window.open('../New/FeedbackV4.aspx?' + par('foo'), ..."
```

(note the added “?”)

with

```
<script>
function par(elid) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elid);
  return encodeURI(elem.name) + '=' + encodeURI(elem.value);
}
</script>
```