# Value not being able to pass from one page to other

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, iframe

This is how i pass value to the page called in iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshConversatio() {
            document.getElementById('ifrmConversation').src = 'Default2.aspx?id=' + document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
        }

    </script>
```

This is How i recieve value in othe page which is being loaded in iframe

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        function myLoad() {
            document.getElementById('<%=hdn.ClientID%>').Value = getParameterByName("id");
        }
    </script>


       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        myLoad();
    </script>
```

I think that there is problem somewhere (might be in myLoad() ) because i am not able to recieve passed value. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this SO answer to know how to call a function in iframe from parent window:

[Calling javascript function in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe)

Comment: @BlaxingCoder Thank you for your answer, but i am able to call iframe page, but not being able to pass hidden field value successfully

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of hidden field try the following:

```
var abc =  document.getElementById('hdn');
```

or

```
var abc =  document.getElementById('hdn').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample way

code

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_myhiddenfield" runat="server" Value="hidden value"/>
```

You can use a Javascript function to insert the value into your *onclick* attribute

**onclick**

```
onclick="window.open('../New/FeedbackV4.aspx'+GetHFValue(),'FeedbackWindow','width=960,height=640,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes')"
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetHFValue() {
        var hf_value = '?' + document.getElementById("<%= hf_myhiddenfield.ClientID %>").value;
        return hf_value;
    }
</script>
```

The above code sample is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893341/passing-a-querystring-value-through-a-javascript-window-open)

and Call this below code for get query string value

```
/*
* <summary>
* Get the querystring value
* </summary>
* <param name="key">A string contains the querystring key</param>
* <param name="defaultVal">Object which get returns when there is not key</param>
**/
function getQuerystring(key, defaultVal) {
    if (defaultVal == null) {
        defaultVal = "";
    }
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (qs == null) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
    else {
        return qs[1];
    }
}
```